# xslt - how to remove grouping-separator/reformat number to correct xs:double type?

Tags: xml, xslt, decimal, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm currently working with inconsistent data and I'm having issue with converting few values so that they are actually consistent.

This is sample from the XML file that I have to work with:

```
<RootRequest>   
    <Data>
        <APPLICATION_ID>3158997</APPLICATION_ID>
        <APPLICATION_DATE>1.9.2019</APPLICATION_DATE>
        <AMOUNT>48597.95</AMOUNT>
        <FINANCED_AMOUNT>48597.95</FINANCED_AMOUNT>
        <DOWNPAYMENT>0</DOWNPAYMENT>
        <RESIDUAL_VALUE>27390.9</RESIDUAL_VALUE>
        <DURATION>36</DURATION>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    <APPLICATION_ID>4127974</APPLICATION_ID>    
        <APPLICATION_DATE>1.9.2019</APPLICATION_DATE>
    <AMOUNT>22.800,00</AMOUNT>
    <FINANCED_AMOUNT>17.300,00</FINANCED_AMOUNT>
    <DOWNPAYMENT>5.500,00</DOWNPAYMENT>
    <RESIDUAL_VALUE>3.000,00</RESIDUAL_VALUE>
    <DURATION>24</DURATION>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    <APPLICATION_ID>3158995</APPLICATION_ID>
    <APPLICATION_DATE>1.9.2019</APPLICATION_DATE>
    <AMOUNT>23903.55</AMOUNT>
    <FINANCED_AMOUNT>23903.55</FINANCED_AMOUNT>
    <DOWNPAYMENT>0</DOWNPAYMENT>
    <RESIDUAL_VALUE>23073.55</RESIDUAL_VALUE>
    <DURATION>6</DURATION>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    <APPLICATION_ID>4127974</APPLICATION_ID>
    <APPLICATION_DATE>1.9.2019</APPLICATION_DATE>
    <AMOUNT>52.800,00</AMOUNT>
    <FINANCED_AMOUNT>77.300,00</FINANCED_AMOUNT>
    <DOWNPAYMENT>5500.84</DOWNPAYMENT>
    <RESIDUAL_VALUE>3000.25</RESIDUAL_VALUE>
    <DURATION />
    </Data>
</RootRequest>
```

as you can see there are inconsistencies for example in element FINANCED_AMOUNT you can see that data differs... in one example it is 17.300,00 in the other it is 23903.55 and I need to have them all be like the second example... so that would be 17300.00 and not 17.300,00...

I have tried using format-number() with xsl:decimal-format:

`<xsl:decimal-format name="decimals" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />`

`format-number(DOWNPAYMENT, '###.###,00', 'decimals')`

but it doesnt work... it returns an error saying

**invalid lexical value** - cannot convert parameter at position [1] of the format-number function.
I wanted to try removing thousand separator but dont know if it is possible...

here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="decimals" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />
    <xsl:template match="RootRequest">
        <xsl:element name="Requests">
            <xsl:for-each select="Data">
                <xsl:call-template name="prepRequest" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="prepRequest">
        <xsl:element name="Request">
                        <xsl:element name="Amount">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(FINANCED_AMOUNT, '###.###,00', 'decimals')" />
                        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone help me with this topic?

Comment: Well, edit the files and correct them to use a consistent format or try to correct the programmatically e.g. with `replace`, `translate` or `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: I cannot use replace or translate because of inconsistencies... if I use oe of these functions... then the output of them would be not quite right... if you take this for example: translate('17.300,00', '.', '') then the result is ok but what about this: translate('23903.55', '.', '') then the result is not going to be OK + I cant edit the files this is what I was given + its just a snippet of data, there are like 30000 <Data> elements in this file

Comment: Well, you can certain first check the format with e.g. `matches` and then use the proper `replace` call you need for a particular match.

Comment: We can't help you unless you first do the analysis of what set of data formats are found in the file and how you want each one of them to be treated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][normalize-space()][not(. castable as xs:decimal)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". => translate(',.', '.') => xs:decimal() => format-number( '0.00')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```